# How can I make a Python deserialization function useable from another module?

Tags: python, serialization, scope

I have some serialization and deserialization code which works well within one module (and within the universe of classes I care about).  E.g.

```
class A(...):
    ...

class B(...):
    ...

def serialize( obj ):
    ...

def deserialize( string ):
    ...

assert( obj == deserialize( serialize( obj ) ) )
```

However, if I define a class in another module and import `serialize` and `deserialize` there, serialization works but I have a problem with deserialization.  The deserialization function doesn't "know" about the class definition in the other module and can't instantiate an instance.

So far, I've used two different ways to work around this.  One is by passing `globals()` and `locals()` into `deserialize` which then calls `eval` with them.  Another has the caller pass in `__name__` and `deserialize` call `inspect.getmembers( sys.modules[ passedInName ] )`.  I could also require registering every serializable class in some list visible to `deserialize`.

But, I don't like any of those workarounds.  Is there a better way?

(If it matters I need to use Python 2.7 because that's what we have at work.)

ADDED: I've coded up a version of the "register every serializable class in some list" strategy based on the `ABCMeta` metaclass which doesn't seem too horrible.  It does involve looking in `_abc_registry` which feels a little wrong.

Comment: Is there some reason not to use `pickle` or `joblib` or some other standard serialization tool?

Comment: Yes.  I tried to keep the question direct so didn't go into great detail about the situation.  One of them is that I am building off of an existing, text based serialization scheme.  It is useful for us for the resulting string to be human readable.  But the existing scheme is just too limited for me because it is limited mostly to tuples of basic types.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is probably in your last test:

```
assert( obj == deserialize( serialize( obj ) ) )
```

The objects will be "practically equal", but there will be two different instances of the same
class, having all members the same.

You may check it by asking the objects for `id(obj)` value and you will get different values.

To fix that (if you want to allow two different instances being equal) is to add `__eq__` to your
classes.

Here is my attempt to define such classes plus added `serialize` and `deserialize` using JSON
string. To show, that `serialize` and `deserialize` function may live in other module than classes,
they are put into different module:

### File `classroom.py`:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __repr__(self):
        templ = "<A: a:{self.a} b: {self.b}>"
        return templ.format(self=self)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.a == other.a) and (self.b == other.b)


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, c, d):
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

    def __repr__(self):
        templ = "<B: c:{self.c} d: {self.c}>"
        return templ.format(self=self)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.c == other.c) and (self.d == other.d)
```

### File `serdeser.py`:

```
import json


def serialize(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, A):
        return json.dumps({"type": "A", "args": {"a": obj.a, "b": obj.b}})
    elif isinstance(obj, B):
        return json.dumps({"type": "B", "args": {"c": obj.c, "d": obj.d}})
    else:
        raise ValueError()


def deserialize(string):
    dct = json.loads(string)
    objtype = dct.get("type")
    if objtype == "A":
        return A(**dct["args"])
    elif objtype == "B":
        return B(**dct["args"])
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unknown type of data")
```

## Testing the code: `test_ser.py`

Here are my tests (using `pytest`). I put it into file `test_ser.py`:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def a_instance():
    from serdeser import A
    return A(11, 12)


@pytest.fixture
def a_serialized(a_instance):
    from serdeser import serialize
    return serialize(a_instance)


@pytest.fixture
def b_instance():
    from serdeser import B
    return B(88, 99)


@pytest.fixture
def b_serialized(b_instance):
    from serdeser import serialize
    return serialize(b_instance)


def test_A(a_instance, a_serialized):
    from serdeser import deserialize
    assert a_instance == deserialize(a_serialized)


def test_B(b_instance, b_serialized):
    from serdeser import deserialize
    assert b_instance == deserialize(b_serialized)
```

You shall have `pytest` installed:

```
$ pip install pytest
```

To run the test (and assuming the file `serdeser.py` and `classroom.py` are in
the same directory:

```
$ py.test -sv test_ser.py                                                              (env: stack) 
========================================= test session starts =========================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.9 -- py-1.4.30 -- pytest-2.7.2 -- /home/javl/.virtualenvs/stack/bin/python2
rootdir: /home/javl/sandbox/stack, inifile: 
collected 2 items 

test_ser.py::test_A PASSED
test_ser.py::test_B PASSED

====================================== 2 passed in 0.01 seconds =======================================
```

All is passing to me.

If you experience problem with importing the `serdeser` module from current directory, then use:

```
$ EXPORT PYTHONPATH="."
```

In my tests, I never import anything from `serdeser` into global scope, only into scope of test case
function.

There shall be no problem for import function `deserialize` with knowledge of class `A` as they are
defined within the same module.

Comment: Thanks.  You are right about `__eq__` and similar.  The classes I've been working with have them, but I'll add them to any new ones.  But I do need deserialize to work with classes defined in different modules.

Comment: @Uncorrelated I have separated class definitions into file `classroom.py`. So `serialize` and `deserialize` are in different module than the classes and all still works.